# cordova ionic buttons not working within multiple modals

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bootstrap-modal

This is such a bizarre issue that I don't even know how to properly title the question.

My app lists multiple events.  Some events require the user to acknowledge a "waiver" form.  The events that require waiver forms have a button "sign waiver form".  On all events requiring waiver forms, the waiver form button launches a modal and within that modal there is a checkbox acknowledging the waiver form...when the user checks that checkbox, it activates the "accept now" button.

On the first event the user goes into the checkbox activates the "accept now" button.  But if the user exits the modal (regardless if the actually click the "accept now" button or not) and goes back in to the same event modal OR exits and goes to another event modal, clicking the checkbox fails activate the "accept now" button.  The user has to leave the app, come back in again.  It only works on the first modal - once - and then won't work on the same modal or any other modal after that.

Heres the modal:

```
  <script id="waiverModal.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-modal-view class="modalCenter">
      <ion-header-bar align-title="center" style="text-align:center;">
        <span style="color:#4e8cf9;text-align:center;">{{club.clubInfo.clSiteName}} LIABILITY/WAIVER FORM
        <br>Event Requires Accepting The Waiver</span>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-init="fileLoaded=0" style="top:25px;padding-top:5px;">
        <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100% z-index:1000;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);" ng-if="fileLoaded==0">
          <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:100px;">
              <div style="background-color:#387ef5;color:white;width:100%;border-radius:10px;">Loading file...</div>
              <div><img style="height:100px;" ng-src="img/ajax_loading.gif"></div>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <!-- ng-model="waiverBox" ng-model="waiverForm" -->
        <div style="padding:5px;font-size:12px;margin-top:25px;"><pre ng-include src="club.ceFormPath" onload="fileLoaded=1"></pre></div>
        <div style="margin:15px;"><input type="checkbox" style="width:30px;height:30px;" id="waiverBox_{{club.ceID}}" ng-click="doWaiver({{club.ceID}})" /> I have read the Liability/Waiver form</div>
        <div id="" class="item" style="font-size:12px;margin:5px;text-align:left;white-space:normal;">
          <div>By clicking "ACCEPT TERMS" you are agreeing to contents of this liability/waiver form</div>
          <button  id="waiverForm_{{club.ceID}}" style="line-height:5px;min-height:20px;font-weight:bolder ;" type="button" class="button button-small button-modalCustom" disabled ng-click="closeWaiver(2)">ACCEPT TERMS</button>
          <button style="margin-left:25px;line-height:5px;min-height:20px;font-weight:bolder ;" type="button" class="button button-small button-modalCustom button-customColor" ng-click="closeWaiver(1)">CLOSE</button>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-modal-view>
  </script>
```

And the controller function that activates the "accept now" button:

```
  $scope.doWaiver = function(id) {
    var elBox = document.getElementById('waiverBox_'+id) ;
    var elForm = document.getElementById('waiverForm_'+id)
    if (elBox.checked == true) {
      elForm.disabled = false ;
      elForm.style.backgroundColor = "#387ef5" ;
      elForm.style.color = "white" ;
    } else {
      elForm.disabled = true ;
      elForm.style.backgroundColor = "white" ;
      elForm.style.color = "#387ef5" ;
    }
  }
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out why it works ONCE...and then not again until the user closes the app and comes back in again.

Upon further troubleshooting I found that AFTER the first check/uncheck box, that same checkbox or any other modal checkbox registers as "true" whether its being checked OR unchecked.

**UPDATE: I added an ng-model to both the checkbox and button.**  `ng-model='waiverBox_[club.ceID]'` and `ng-model='waiverForm_[club.ceID]'` and then also added some additional code the modal close.  It works better now, but upon entry back into the modal, the checkbox is unchecked, the button is inactive and when I click the checkbox nothing happens...not even a change/click firing of the event function.  Then I uncheck the box and it fires, check the box again and it all works.  But why isn't the first check of the checkbox working?

```
  $scope.closeWaiver = function(type,id) {
    var elBox = document.getElementById('waiverBox_'+id) ;
    var elForm = document.getElementById('waiverForm_'+id) ;
    elBox.checked = false ;
    elForm.disabled = true ;
    $scope["waiverBox_" +id] = false ;
    elForm.style.backgroundColor = "white" ;
    elForm.style.color = "#387ef5" ;    
    if (type == 1) {
      $scope.closeModal() ;
    } else if (type == 2) {
      clubService.getWaiver($scope.club.cID,$scope.club.ceID,$scope.club.ceLiability)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response[0].success == true) {
          // waiver form accepted
          $scope.closeModal() ;
          $scope.club.ceForm = 1 ;
          $rootScope.refreshClubs = 1 ;
          alert(response[0].msg);
          $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
            $state.go("tab.clubs",null,{reload:true});  
          });
        }
      }) ; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Take some screenshots perhaps of what is happening. Sometimes pictures are worth  more than a wall of text! ;-)

Comment: I'm not familiar with this..   `<script id="waiverModal.html" type="text/ng-template">`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACYu94hLg4I

Comment: What version of Ionic are you using BTW? V1 or above?

Comment: @JGFMK  Ionic V1  .  The `<script>` tag loads an external file into the modal versus manually defining the modal in the HTML file.

Comment: Ah right. I've only used Ionic v2 and v3 so far...

Comment: Yeah, next month I begin the tedious process of migrating from V1 to V3 (or V4)...its going to be a complete rewrite of my app - thus I have been avoiding it for quite sometime.

Comment: The behavior is working better now.  First time in the modal everything works fine...but leave the modal, come back in and the checkbox doesn't work until the second click - everything fires properly on the second click, nothing fires on the first click (after re-entry)